# Swift - Temporary URL?

Tags: amazon-s3, swift3

I need to upload to amazon S3 and the function requires a URL where it can pick the file from. I don't want to save images because of some manipulation of images but I want to upload them directly to S3 as data objects. Is there a way to fake a temporary URL or something like that?

```
    request?.body = fileUrl as URL!
    request?.key = key
    request?.bucket = self.bucket
```